# Xcode 10.1 - Swift 4.2 - locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) has been renamed to locationManager(_:didUpdate:)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location

I have this weird issue with Core Locations that just started happening my swift 4.2 project with Xcode 10.1:
The compiler now rejects the following method implementation of `CLLocationManagerDelegate`:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
 //code
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> 'locationManager(*:didUpdateLocations:)' has been renamed to
>   'locationManager(*:didUpdate:)'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg1XD.png)

However the latest Apple documentation does not document this change and updating the parameter name causes the following warning to appear, which seems to indicate that it's an Xcode bug:

> Instance method 'locationManager(*:didUpdate:)' nearly matches
>   optional requirement 'locationManager(*:didUpdateLocations:)' of
>   protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'.
>   Rename to 'locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)' to satisfy this requirement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYpT1.png)

Also, this only happens when building for a Simulator device. I do not get this error when building for my iPhone that runs an earlier iOS version (11.4.2).
Changing the parameter name works on simulator (i.e., the method gets called) but not my device. So I am now in a place where I need to update the code each time I move from Simulator to device and vice versa.

Any suggestions on how I can get rid of this issue would be most appreciated!

Comment: I am using the same Xcode 10.1 - Swift 4.2 and this works for me `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
 //code
} `  you can try making it public like  `public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
 //code
} `

Comment: I tried making it public but that did not fix it. This bug is awfully weird.

Comment: I am facing the same issue